# The editing help contains a non-working example for putting blockquotes into lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Below is the text from [Stack Overflow's editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists). As you see 4th item from editing help is renedered as 1 so it looks like a bug. If it's not a bug what is the way of putting blockquote into list item without breaking list?

1. Lists in a list item:

   - Indented four spaces.

     - indented eight spaces.
   - Four spaces again.
2. Multiple paragraphs in a list items:
   It's best to indent the paragraphs four spaces
   You can get away with three, but it can get
   confusing when you nest other things.
   Stick to four.

   We indented the first line an extra space to align
   it with these paragraphs.  In real use, we might do
   that to the entire list so that all items line up.

   This paragraph is still part of the list item, but it looks messy to humans.  So it's a good idea to wrap your nested paragraphs manually, as we did with the first two.
3. Blockquotes in a list item:

> Skip a line and
>   indent the >'s four spaces.

4. Preformatted text in a list item:

   ```
   Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
   That's four spaces for the list
   and four to trigger the code block.
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what is the way of putting blockquote into list item without breaking list?

Do it like the editing help *says*, not like it *does* :)

I'll fix the editing help example (will be in the next build of the site).

### Markdown:

```
1. Blockquotes in a list item:

    > Skip a line and
    > indent the >'s four spaces.

2. Preformatted text in a list item:
```

### Rendered version:

1. Blockquotes in a list item:

   > Skip a line and
   >   indent the >'s four spaces.
2. Preformatted text in a list item: